# HTML tables while printing are cut from right side in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer-11

i am having a scenario where tables come from server and we simply load it into a DIV and we also provide a fancy BUTTON called print which simply executes `WINDOW.print()` function.

we also do have  `@media print ( print media Query )`, where we specify what to display and what not to.

" shrink to fit " option in chrome works perfectly and the table which is to be printed shrinks to fit the page but the same does not work in Internet Explorer.

i was searching for a solution and i read somewhere that " shrink to fit " of INTERNET EXPLORER won't work for static structures like "table" which does not respect the HTML flow.

this is what MICROSOFT has to say..

Some webpages specify exactly where text should print on the page. If the webpage you're printing specifies exactly where the text should print, Shrink To Fit will not work. You can work around this problem by setting a custom scale in print preview. For more information about print preview, see Preview the appearance of a printed webpage.

after trying and searching a lot i came up with a solution of making a calculation and setting " zoom " style for the div in " print media query "

i am looking for a perfect and better solution as i know my solution is not at all good. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use "px" for table and TD dimension. Set width:100% for table (or n% for TD) and let the content decide where to place.